# Verify all mock usages

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to verify all usages of my mock, even those, which are wrapped with `try-catch`. I expected Strict mock to do the job, but it throws exception inside `try` which being swallowed by following `catch` and when I try to `VerifyAll()` afterwards, Moq cannot find any usages.
Apart from checking all possible calls manually with `Verify()` do I have any other option to check all usages of the Mock?

Here is a example of strict mock which doesn't work:

```
[Test]
public void WhenCondition_ThenResult()
{
    var client = new Mock<IClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    try
    {
        client.Object.Send(null);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    client.VerifyAll(); //no errors
}
```

Comment: @sloth the question which you marked as 'answered before' has a workaround instead of answer and doesn't suits me, as I stated in a question, and things might change for last 5 years. So I'll be much appreciated if you let the question live.

Comment: Nothing has changed. Moq still throws a `MockException` when using `MockBehavior.Strict` and calling a method that was not set up, and the workaround works. Why do you catch all exceptions in the first place?

Comment: It's being used in application life cycle.